# Gradle repositories in Gradle settings instead of build?

Tags: maven, gradle

In Maven, you can store the list of repositories in settings.xml, which means each developer can have his own settings (when you are inside a company, you will use the local Nexus as a mirror, but when outside, you will use Maven Central).

How do you do that with Gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gradle init script for that. these init scripts can live in the  `~/.gradle/init.d/` folder. Having on (e.g. `default-repos.gradle`) with adding default repositories can look like this:

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'http://nexus.local.org'
        }
    }
}`